Selenium Chromedriver not responding using a Class
I'm trying to use chromedriver from a Class. I'm declaring driver as a global variable, inside the class file.. but when I do that, I get an error: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]
If I don't declare the driver as a global, then chrome closes..
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
#File: webdriver.py
global driver

class CustWebDriver:

    def __init__(self,temp_download_dir):
        self.temp_download_dir=temp_download_dir
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

    def start_driver(self):
        service = Service(r'C:\Scrappers\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
        service.start()
        driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options=self.chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://www.google.cl")  # IT WORKS
        return driver


#File main.py

import Clases.webdriver as WD

driver1=WD.CustWebDriver(temp_download_dir)
driver1=driver1.start_driver()

link='https://www.yahoo.com'  
driver1.get(link)               # NOT WORKING

